# Disable SQL query compilation

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016

While executing below code in my post deployment script:

```
SELECT @currentDBVersion;
IF @currentDBVersion IS NULL GOTO Script1
ELSE IF @currentDBVersion = 1 GOTO Script2
ELSE GOTO ScriptData

Script1:
:r .\Scripts\Script1.sql
Script2: 
:r .\Scripts\Script2.sql
ScriptData:
-- Execute Data
```

In case of @currentDBVersion = 1, SQL is compiling Script1. Is there any way,  i can avoid compiling Script1.

Comment: Is it part of SSDT project?

Comment: No its VS database project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added a reference in the post deployment script, it will compile the script file.
Try using variables to store the file name.